# Java Timer class issue- Timer start again upon code deployment

Tags: java, timer

I have the below code in which SchedularMain class is getting called from  init in web.xml upon server start or new deployment. The code will perform task after 5 min from server startup/ deployment and repeat task after 24 hours as per the  logic.

Problem: If code gets deployed twice or thrice within 24 hours interval the task gets generated twice or thrice instead of only once in 24 hours cycle. As schedular gets re initiated every time. How can i prevent this issue.

Requirement: I want the task to take place every Wednesday at 3PM IST every week and the code should not be dependent on Deployment/ Server restart issue as described above. Please help.

```
public class SchedulerMain {
   public void startMethod(){

   long ONCE_PER_DAY = 1000*60*60*24;

   Timer timer = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
   ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class        
   timer.schedule(st, 1000*60*60*5, ONCE_PER_DAY);// Create Repetitively task for every 24hours.

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ScheduledExecutorService` and submit your task with certain calculated delay as `Runnable` or `Callable`

Comment: Thanks rkosegi .... let me try

Comment: rkosegi one query schedualrExecutor will not get reoloaded upon server restart ?? are you sure

Comment: @Ranoprio : Not sure if I got your question.